# How to test if object property exists before reading its value?

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, autoit

My Internet Explorer object `$oIE`, won't let me access the page's body property if it concerns a PDF file (as opposed to a HTML page). If I try to access that property, my code breaks. Here is how I call it:

```
_IEAction($oIE, 'saveas')
```

But it errors:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Include\IE.au3" (1959) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.:
$oObject.document.execCommand("SaveAs")
$oObject.document^ ERROR
```

I need to iterate over a few pages of PDF files and save them to disk. This error is thrown only when the page is a PDF document; a normal HTML page works fine. How to check if the document body property exists? If it doesn't, it means the page is a PDF (I need to save it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use the InetGet function to save the PDF's and check the URL to see if it is a PDF file.

Here is a simple example using InetGet.

```
InetGet("http://careers.stackoverflow.com/stack_overflow_careers.pdf", @ScriptDir & "\stack_overflow_careers.pdf")
```

Here is an example of finding all PDF URL's on a page and downloading those PDF's.

```
#include <IE.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

DownloadAllPDFs("http://careers.stackoverflow.com/resources/great-job-listing")

Func DownloadAllPDFs($URL)
    Local $oIE = _IECreate($URL)
    Local $oLinks = _IELinkGetCollection($oIE)
    Dim $aPDFLinks[1]

    For $oLink In $oLinks
        If StringInStr($oLink.href, ".pdf") Then
            _ArrayAdd($aPDFLinks, $oLink.href)
        EndIf
    Next

    Local $iArraySize = UBound($aPDFLinks) - 1

    ConsoleWrite("Number of PDF Files found: " & $iArraySize)
    ;_ArrayDisplay($aPDFLinks)
    If $iArraySize > 0 Then
        For $i = 1 To $iArraySize
            InetGet($aPDFLinks[$i], @ScriptDir & "\" & $i & ".pdf")
        Next
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>DownloadAllPDFs
```

Here is an example of navigating to a URL, and downloading the file if it is a PDF.

```
#include <IE.au3>

NavigateAndDownload()

Func NavigateAndDownload()
    Local $oIE = _IECreate()
    _IENavigate($oIE, "http://careers.stackoverflow.com/stack_overflow_careers.pdf", 0)
    Sleep(5000)
    $sURL = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
    If StringInStr($sURL, ".pdf") Then InetGet($sURL, @ScriptDir & "\test.pdf")
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you need to do error handling you can do

```
_IEAction($oIE, 'saveas')
if (@error) then
;error handling here
endif
```

so then you can choose only to save the files if you dont get any errors.

I think you could also look at the url with `_IEPropertyGet` and see if it ends with ".pdf"